# Using 'model.android.ndk' command in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, java-native-interface

I'm using gradle 4.4 and I can't the 'ndk' command is not found. This is my build.gradle of the application:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'cpp'


android {
    System.setProperty('SYS', 'android')
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}
model {
    android.ndk {
        moduleName "native-lib"
      }
}
```

I don't know what the problem is but i get the error:

> The following model rules could not be applied due to unbound inputs
>   and/or subjects:
>
> android.ndk { ... } @ app\build.gradle line 27, column 5
>       subject:
>         - android.ndk Object [*]
>
> [*] - indicates that a model item could not be found for the path or
>   type.

which refers to the line of the 'ndk' command.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you updgrade from the old experimental gradle plugin? The `model` block isn't used anymore AFAIK, i.e. it should just be `android ... { ndk { ... } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google essentially discontinued the experimental NDK plugin. Please follow their official guide to migrate to the stable plugin: [*Migrate to Stable Gradle for NDK Support using CMake and ndk-build*](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental/migrate-to-stable).

If you have problems with this tutorial, and you need more guidance, please don't hesitate to ask here.